# Remote desktop connection - No password

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

In our setup we have a network of 6 to 8 computer with no one of them having password and it logs straight on with operator user id. I want control these systems remotely but due to no password it does not allow me to do so. 
I can get into one computer by team viewer but try to do RDP but it is not working.

Any alternate solution as we cannot assign password to our system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see: [Is there any way to enable Remote Desktop Connection with a password without setting a password on the OS?](http://superuser.com/questions/161845/is-there-any-way-to-enable-remote-desktop-connection-with-a-password-without-set?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has been locked and I am prevented from providing an answer.  You should try VNC.  It uses a different authentication mechanism and will allow you to remote control without the need for registry hacks.  VNC is a well known solution and is free.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not recommended** for various security reasons, but you should be able to enable RDP sans password with the following steps:
1.  Open up Administrative tools
2.  Open up Local Security Policy
3.  Expand Local Policies and click on Security Options
4.  Double click on "Accounts:  Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only" and click Disabled
5.  Reboot.

You can also use alternatives like Team Viewer (as you've tried) or VNC.

Comment: If you ran a VNC server you better use a password.  You will be hacked if you don't that is a guarantee.